# How to integrate Bazel tool with the CI server Jenkins. so that i can automate the build and some post build actions.

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bazel

How can i integrate the Bazel Build tool with the continuous integration server Jenkins. so that i can automate the build process and some post build actions. With a single commit to the github repo we need to invoke the bazel and jenkins to get the artifact. Can anyone help me with a solution.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what specific issue are you running into?

Comment: It would be really informative if you provide few inputs about what exactly are you trying to achieve? Your question doesn't elaborate much.

Comment: [cirrus CI](https://cirrus-ci.org/examples/#bazel) has native support for Bazel.